# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Llevo tiempo intentando solucionar este error pero no lo entiendo.

Estoy trabajando en python con las librerías de openpyxl y pandas, para trabajar dataframes y Excel, lo que intento hacer es pasar los datos que se encuentran dentro del dataframe al excel mediante openpyxl (no mediante pandas), lo hice siguiendo la documentación de openpyxl, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me tira el error --> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as opx
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

#Conexion BBDD
conexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=srv;DATABASE=BD;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

#Query a la BBDD
query = "SELECT top 3 * FROM contratos"
pd_query = pd.read_sql_query(query, conexion)

#Creacion del Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(pd_query)

#Creacion de Workbook
wb = opx.Workbook('Prototipo.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save('path')
```

El error viene del FOR en la parte del append.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a solucionar este error, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: [La documentación](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active) dice que ws.active puede devolver None. No profundisan el por que, pero al menos te da una idea de lo que está pasando. Estás seguro de que tu archivo xlsx tiene hojas?

Comment: Si quieres que te pueda ayudar mejor, me vendría genial que pusieras una muestra (no es necesario que sean datos reales) de la tabla contratos.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó tu ayuda, efectivamente lo que estaba vacío era la hoja de ws.active y por eso no dejaba insertar en esa hoja